# Python - Differential equation solver for time-dependent coefficients gives different dynamics for different time offsets

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, solver, differential-equations

I am solving the dynamics of a system when it interacts with a pulse, which basically is solving a time-dependent differential equation. In general it works fine, but whenever I take the bandwidth of the pulse small, i.e. around unity, the solver depends on where the pulse starts t0.
Let me give you the code and some pictures

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import scipy as scipy

## Pulses 

def Box(t):
    return (abs(t-t0) < tau)
    #return  np.exp(-(t - t0)**2.0/(tau ** 2.0))


## Differential eq.
def Leq(t,u,pulse): 
    v=u[:16].reshape(4,4)
    a0=u[16] 
    da0=-a0+pulse(t)*E_0
    
    M=np.array([[-1,0,a0,0],\
                [0,-1,0,-a0],\
                [a0,0,-1,0],\
                [0,-a0,0,-1]])*kappa
    Dr=np.array([[1,1j,0,0],\
                [1j,1,0,0],\
                [0,0,1,1j],\
                [0,0,1j,1]])*kappa/2.0

    
    dv=M.dot(v)+v.dot(M)+Dr
    
    return np.concatenate([dv.flatten(), [da0]])
## Covariance matrix

cov0=np.array([[1,1j,0,0],\
                [1j,1,0,0],\
                [0,0,1,1j],\
                [0,0,1j,1]])/4 ##initial vector
cov0 = cov0.reshape(-1);   ## vectorize initial vector

a0_in=np.zeros((1,1),dtype=np.complex64) ##initial vector
a0_in = a0_in.reshape(-1);   ## vectorize initial vector
u_0=np.concatenate([cov0, a0_in])

### Parameters 
kappa=1.0 ##adimenstional kappa: kappa0/kappa 
tau=1.0  ##bandwidth pump

#Eth=kappa0*kappa/g  ##threshold intensity 
E_0=0.8 # pump intensity normalized to threshold 

t0=2.0   ##off set 

Tmax=10 ##max value for time
Nmax=100000 ##number of steps
dt=Tmax/Nmax  ##increment of time

t=np.linspace(0.0,Tmax,Nmax+1)

Box_sol=solve_ivp(Leq, [min(t),max(t)] , u_0, t_eval= t, args=(Box,))
print(Box_sol.y[0:16,int(Nmax/2)].reshape(4,4))
```

and then just some expectation values and the plotting.

[image: Proper dyanmics]

[image: Not good dynamics]

As you can see from the pictures, the parameters are the same, the only difference is the time shift t0. It seems as whenever the pulse's bandwidth is small, I have to start really close to t=0, which I don't fully understand why. It should,'t be like that.

It is a problem of the solver? If so, what can I do to fix it? I'm now worried that this problem can manifest in other simulations I am running and I don't realise.

Thanks,
Joan.

Comment: Take a look at, for example, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612133/scipy-integrate-ode-gives-up-on-integration), and of course @LutzLehmann's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known behavior, there have been several questions on this topic.

In short, it is the step size controller. The assumption behind it is that the ODE function is smooth to a high order, and that local behavior informs the global behavior in a medium range. Thus if you start flat, with vanishing higher derivatives, the step size is quickly increased. If the situation is unfortunate, this will jump over the non-smooth bump in all stages of the integrator step.

There are two strategies to avoid that

- set `max_step` to `2*tau` so that the bump is surely encountered, the step size selection will make sure that the sampling is dense around the jumps.
- use separate integration for the pieces of the jump, so that the control input inside each segment is a constant.

[image]

The first variant is in a small way an abuse of the step size controller, as it works outside specifications in some heuristic emergency mode around the jumps. The second variant requires a little more coding effort, but will have less internal steps, as the ODE function for each segment is again completely smooth.